# Does not return contact ID to go to another page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, contact, salesforce-id, aura-attribute

When I check which value is returned at the click of a button, null always returns to me. And when I click on the button to go to another page, it always goes to another page (it makes no difference what or not). **How to fix it to go to the page only for the entered contactId, if it exists.**

LoginPageComponent

```
<aura:component controller="Login" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="contactId" type="id"/>
<aura:attribute name="login" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="password" type="String"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.getContact}"/>

            <p class="l"> Login </p>

            <ui:inputEmail class="email" value="{!v.login}" placeholder="Enter your username"/>  

            <p class="l"> Password </p>

            <ui:inputSecret class="password" value="{!v.password}" placeholder="Password" /> 

          <lightning:button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" label="Login" onclick="{!c.handleValueChange}" value="{!v.contactId}"/>
```

LoginPageController

```
({
getContact : function(component) {
    var login = component.get('v.login');
    var password = component.get('v.password');
    var action = component.get("c.getContactId");
    action.setParams({
        login: login,
        password: component.get('v.password')
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
         var state = response.getState();
         if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.contactId", response.getReturnValue());
         }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

 handleValueChange : function(component, event) {
    var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
    evt.setParams({
        componentDef : "c:UserPage",
        componentAttributes: {
            contactId : event.getParam("value")
        }
    });
   evt.fire();
}
})
```

LoginClass

```
public with sharing class Login {

@AuraEnabled
public static Id getContactId (String login, String password){

    List<Contact> contacts = [Select Id FROM Contact Where Email =: login AND Password__c =: password];
    if (contacts.size() > 0 )
        return contacts[0].Id;
    else
        return null;
 }
}
```

*I have been sitting with this for a long time and almost in despair. Can someone please help?*

Answer (score 1):

You have to first retrieve the value from the event in the controller and then navigate only if there is any value like below:

```
 handleValueChange : function(component, event) {

    var contactId = event.getSource().get("v.value");
    if(contactId){
        var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
        evt.setParams({
            componentDef : "c:UserPage",
            componentAttributes: {
                contactId : contactId 
            }
        });
        evt.fire();     

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function {c.getContact} is being called on init at which point, the username/password fields are empty. Shouldn't it be called on a button click?

Component:

```
<lightning:button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" label="Login" onclick="{!c.getContact}" value="{!v.contactId}"/>
```

Controller:

```
   ({
    getContact: function(component) {
        var login = component.get('v.login');
        var password = component.get('v.password');
        var action = component.get("c.getContactId");
        action.setParams({
            login: login,
            password: component.get('v.password')
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                let contactIdFound = response.getReturnValue();
                component.set("v.contactId", contactIdFound);
                var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
                evt.setParams({
                    componentDef: "c:UserPage",
                    componentAttributes: {
                        contactId: contactIdFound
                    }
                });
                evt.fire();
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    handleValueChange: function(component, event) {
        //moved to getcontact
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining your two answers, here's what happened

```
getContact: function(component) {
    var login = component.get('v.login');
    var password = component.get('v.password');
    var action = component.get("c.getContactId");
    action.setParams({
        login: login,
        password: component.get('v.password')
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            let contactIdFound = response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.contactId", contactIdFound);

            let contactId = component.get('v.contactId');

            if(contactId){
                var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
                evt.setParams({
                    componentDef: "c:UserPage",
                    componentAttributes: {
                        contactId: contactId
                    }
                });
                evt.fire();
            }
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

Although, if you remove the attribute, it turns out the same

```
getContact: function(component) {
    var login = component.get('v.login');
    var password = component.get('v.password');
    var action = component.get("c.getContactId");
    action.setParams({
        login: login,
        password: component.get('v.password')
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            let contactIdFound = response.getReturnValue();

            if(contactIdFound){
            var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
            evt.setParams({
                componentDef: "c:UserPage",
                componentAttributes: {
                    contactId: contactIdFound
                }
            });
            evt.fire();
            }
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

Buttom:

```
<lightning:button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" label="Login" onclick="{!c.getContact}"/>
```

Now it goes only if the password and login match and exist in the table. *But I'm not very sure if my own page opens for each contact?* Anyway, thanks to everyone for the answers)